# jqgrid can I label rows?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, label, row, names

jqgrid has the ability to label columns with the property colNames. I need to have col labels and row labels for a project.  Is there a way to replace the row numbers with labels or titles?

I looked in the jqgrid documentation options but didn't see rownames or anything about row titles, labels etc.

Comment: Just make a rowName column and put the names in it.

Comment: @Barmar - that sounds like a good answer to me.

Comment: Thanks, that's my new current solution, although it looks like regular data. It would be better if I could actually replace the 1,2,3 on the rows with some title or label.

Comment: @danielsavage change the style of your rowName column using formatter or simply by css.. it looks different then other cols